# PointToPosition Alternative for RecycleView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm replacing a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) by the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), but I'm using a [pointToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#pointToPosition%28int,%20int%29) method, is there any equivalent?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For RecyclerView you have [findChildViewUnder (float x, float y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findChildViewUnder(float,%20float)).
This method returns a child View which you can then use to retrieve the adapter position using [getChildAdapterPosition(View child)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getChildAdapterPosition(android.view.View)).

Answer (score 3):

This will get you the View at (x, y) in the parent RecyclerView:

```
View targetView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
```

And this gets you the position of the item within the underlying data set currently represented by that View:

```
recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(targetView);
```